# iOS - update a framework

Tags: ios, frameworks

I built an app that uses a third party SDK. Recently I had to update the SDK with a new version. I removed the framework files from my application folder, copied the new ones, added them to the project, but it seems XCode is caching the old version.

I tried Clean, tried to delete Derived Data, nothing works. At this point it seems the only available option is to recreate the project and import all the source files. Obviously I am not keen on that. There must be an easy, fast solution to this issue.

Any clue?

Comment: Why don't you use cocoa pods ?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa pods are easy to use and install.

> CocoaPods is the dependency manager for Objective-C projects. It has
>   thousands of libraries and can help you scale your projects elegantly.
>   Ultimately, its goal is to improve discoverability of, and engagement
>   in, third party open-source libraries, by creating a more centralized
>   ecosystem.

However the frameworks need to be compatible with cocoa pods which most libraries are. You use terminal to install. This [site](https://medium.com/5-step-ios-tutorials/how-to-use-cocoapods-137df1bbb89a) may give you an idea how to install it.

Comment: The SDK I am using is not open source

Comment: So the SDK is not a bundle package?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I deleted all copies of the old SDK, whether or not they were in my project folder. Seems like XCode was linking to one of them... Another mystery.